# Is it possible to remove 'redunant' code after rendering it on server?

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering

When you render your app on server, you send HTML and bundle that was used for rendering to client to use it for hydration. Considering that after sending the HTML to the client, only the 'logic' part of the app is missing, is it possible to eliminate the 'redundant' code and reduce the bundle size by sending only 'logic' to the client for hydration?

App

```js
export default function App() {
  const [flag, setFlag] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div>
      <h1 onClick={() => setFlag(!flag)}>The flag is {`${flag}`}</h1>
      <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

After SSR you send to client this and the bundle

```html
<div><h1>The flag is <!-- -->false</h1><h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </h2></div>
```

Client already has `<h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </h2>` however our bundle also includes it.

So idea is excluding that part from the bundle and having only this

```js
export default function App() {
  const [flag, setFlag] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div>
      <h1 onClick={() => setFlag(!flag)}>The flag is {`${flag}`}</h1>
      {/** */}
    </div>
  );
}
```

P.S.
I know it is possible to do a reverse, having server not render part and add it on the client side
E.g.

App

```js
const Text = lazy(() => import("./Text.js"));
export default function App() {
  const [flag, setFlag] = useState(false);
  const [isClient, setIsClient] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => setIsClient(true), []);
  return (
    <div>
      <h1 onClick={() => setFlag(!flag)}>The flag is {`${flag}`}</h1>
      <Suspense fallback={"Loading.."}>{isClient && <Text />}</Suspense>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Text

```js
export default function Text() {
  return <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</h1>;
}
```

Comment: I don't think so. The way that React works is that every render is just a call to a function, and what is displayed is the result of that function call. What you're asking for is updating only the parts that change, which is what other libraries/frameworks do, such as Solid and I believe Svelte do (possibly even Vue). React doesn't have that mechanism. Server Components are similar to what you're asking, but that has the line drawn at the component level instead of inside of a single component.